# How to hyperlink email address and target website on xaringan slides

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I want to put my **email address** on xaringan slide with blue color + underlined hyperlink:
I also want to put a **target website** on the slide with a blue color hyperlink.

I tried something like the following for email.

```
E-mail: [aaa@yahoo.com]() \texttt{\href{mailto:aaa@yahoo.com}{\nolinkurl{aaa@yahoo.com}}
```

I also tried something like the following for webpage.

```
I want you to visit this funplace (url(http:\\bbb.com))
```

But both are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add these hrefs according to markdown syntax and wrap them with container class to style them as you need.

---

````
---
title: "Link in Xaringan"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.link-style1 a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.link-style2 a {
 color: blue;
}

```

# Adding Email and website link

E-mail: .link-style1[[example@gmail.com](mailto:example@gmail.com)]

Also visit this page .link-style2[[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)]
````

---

[image: slide with email and website link]